# How to find the top 3 largest values in a 2-dimensional array using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code for a one-dimensional array, but it does not seem to work for a two-dimensional array.

```
dim m as variant, k as long
m = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
for k=1 to 3
    debug.print application.small(m, k)
    debug.print application.large(m, k)
next k
```

My issue is that I want to get the top 3 largest values for each row, i. So If there are 100 rows, there will be 300 numbers which will be retrieved from column, j.

I have tried the following variations below:

Variation  1: I know this is really wrong because I am getting the largest of each data point rather than getting the largest among all the j's in each row. It returns an error every time j>1 because perhaps there is only 1 data point per iteration.

```
Dim i As Long, g As Long, j As Long

ReDim Min_NDate(5, 5) As Variant

For i = 1 To 5
    For g = 1 To 5
        Min_NDate(i, g) = Rnd()
    Next g
Next i

For i = 1 To 5
    For g = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 2
            Debug.Print Application.Large(Min_NDate(i, g), j)
        Next j
    Next g
Next i
```

Variation 2:
Here I get an "Subscript out of range" error due to the fact that I am using a 2-dimensional array however I am only declaring it as 1 dimensional which is Min_NDate(i).

```
Dim i As Long, g As Long, j As Long

ReDim Min_NDate(5, 5) As Variant

For i = 1 To 5
    For g = 1 To 5
        Min_NDate(i, g) = Rnd()
    Next g
Next i

For i = 1 To 5
    For g = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 2
            Debug.Print Application.Large(Min_NDate(i), j)
        Next j
    Next g
Next i
```

Variation 3: It also errors like in Variation 2 because there is no loop with regards to the 2nd dimension, j. Although I was hoping it would be actually realize that there are values in the 2nd dimension and do what I wanted it to do as shown in the portion to do.

```
Dim i As Long, g As Long, j As Long

ReDim Min_NDate(5, 5) As Variant

For i = 1 To 5
    For g = 1 To 5
        Min_NDate(i, g) = Rnd()
    Next g
Next i

For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 2
        Debug.Print Application.Large(Min_NDate(i, g), j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Ideally what I want to happen is this:
Step 1  **(This is probably my main problem because I cannot display it to be in this form before I feed it to the large function)**:

Min_NDate(1, for all j) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Min_NDatE(2, for all j) = [3, 5, 6, 10, 11]

Step 2:

Top 3 Largest of Min_NDate(1, for all j) = [3, 4, 5]

Top 3 Largest of Min_NDate(2, for all j) = [6, 10, 11]

Comment: You could save me (and others) some time in the Immediate window if you verified whether `ReDim Min_NDate(5, 5) As Variant` has an lbound of zero or one for each rank.

Comment: It says in my Locals Window: Variant(0 to 5, 0 to 5) is that the one you mean? By rank you mean, the dimensions right (x,y,z)?

Comment: yes, I needed to know whether there were 5x5 or 6x6 elements in the array and what the index started at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the Index function just like Jeeped mentioned. There is no pre-built way to slice an array unlike in MATLAB where you can slice by typing something like `Min_NDate(1, :)`

The working code is shown below:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long, g As Long, j As Long

ReDim Min_NDate(1 To 2, 1 To 3) As Variant

For i = LBound(Min_NDate, 1) To UBound(Min_NDate, 1)
    For g = LBound(Min_NDate, 2) To UBound(Min_NDate, 2)
        Min_NDate(1, 1) = 100
        Min_NDate(1, 2) = 50
        Min_NDate(1, 3) = 1
        Min_NDate(2, 1) = 25
        Min_NDate(2, 2) = 10
        Min_NDate(2, 3) = 2
    Next g
Next i

For i = LBound(Min_NDate, 1) To UBound(Min_NDate, 1)
    For j = 1 To 2
        Debug.Print Application.Large(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Min_NDate, i, 0), j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: am I also able to retrieve the position inside the array connected to the value debug printed?

Answer (score 2):

You are not looking at the individual elements of each array correctly. wadr, the way you construct For ... Next statements has a lot to do with it.

In **any** array, no matter whether it is 1-D or 2-D (or more) you should **never** hard-code any dimension. Always use the lbound and ubound properties of any rank¹.

When you run `For i = 1 To 5` instead of determining lbounds and ubounds and complicating it with a  nested `For g = 1 To 5` you are skipping over the first element in the array. If you ran,

```
For i = lbound(Min_NDate, 1) To ubound(Min_NDate, 1)
    For g = lbound(Min_NDate, 2) To ubound(Min_NDate, 2)
         Min_NDate(i, g) = Rnd()
    next g
next i
```

This should fill your complete array with random numbers if the .randomize code is correct.

¹ <sub>Rank s the lateral ordinal of a 2-D array. Rank 1 can be thought as by 'row' while rank 2 would be the 'column'. A 1-D array doesn't have to concern with rank although a rank of 1 is not an error.</sub>

Comment: Thanks that makes sense perhaps i'll be better at using arrays. But how about ranking them to get the top 3 largest numbers? I believe the problem still exists even after applying this

Comment: Yeah, that would be largely due to the fact that you asked for the largest this time and not the smallest (which would be always be zero for positive numbers returned by the empty first element). You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and so far I am only addressing the Y.

Comment: Thanks as always. Will try to figure out how to get the largest of a 2-D array. I don't think it's a for-next loop I need for this one. I don't think I should sum the column dimension also.

Comment: If you can pose a question without a Y problem and provide an [mcve]  then I believe your solution is within application.index or array.filter.

Comment: Thanks i guess i'll look into them. Will probably hold off for another day.